# JSoup format ouput of children

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing a document with many entries like this (with JSoup)

```
 <span class="chart_position position-up position-greatest-gains">1</span>
            <h1>Beauty And A Beat</h1>
        <p class="chart_info">
      <a href="/artist/305459/justin-bieber">Justin Bieber Featuring Nicki Minaj</a>            <br>
      Beauty and a Beat          </p>
```

I can extract two seperate lists of title and artist of the song, like this:

```
    Elements song = doc.select("div.chart_listing h1");
    System.out.println("song: " + song);

    Elements li = doc.select("p.chart_info a");
    System.out.println("artists: " + li.text());
```

However, now the output looks like this:

```
<h1>The Lucky Ones</h1>
<h1>Scream &amp; Shout</h1>
<h1>Clarity</h1>
<h1>We Are Young</h1>
<h1>Va Va Voom</h1>
<h1>Catch My Breath</h1>
<h1>I Found You</h1>
<h1>Sorry</h1>
<h1>Leaving</h1>
artists: Justin Bieber Featuring Nicki Minaj Kerli will.i.am & Britney Spears Nicki Minaj Kelly Clarkson The Wanted Ciara Pet Shop Boys
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
1 - Song - Artist
2 - Song - Artist
etc
```

I have been looking at related posts and tried this, but I have not quite figured it out:

```
        Elements parents = doc.select("div.chart_listing h1");
        for (Element parent : parents)
        {
            Elements categories = parent.select("p.chart_info a");
            System.out.print("song: " + parent + " - ");
            System.out.print("artist: " + categories.text() + "\n");
        }
```

This currently outputs a blank song, like this:

```
song: <h1>Beauty And A Beat</h1> - artist: 
song: <h1>The Lucky Ones</h1> - artist: 
song: <h1>Scream &amp; Shout</h1> - artist:
```

Two main questions remain open:

- How do I print the artist belonging to the song? Why is it blanc?
- How do I add the numbering (this is secondary, but would be nice)

Thanks so much!

---EDIT

Solved the first problem by using a larger parent:

```
    Elements parents = doc.select("article.song_review");
    for (Element parent : parents)
    {
        Elements titles = parent.select("h1");
        Elements categories = parent.select("p.chart_info a");
        System.out.print("song: " + titles + " - ");
        System.out.print("artist: " + categories.text() + "\n");
    }
```

Now output looks like this:

```
song: <h1>Beauty And A Beat</h1> - artist: Justin Bieber Featuring Nicki Minaj
song: <h1>The Lucky Ones</h1> - artist: Kerli
song: <h1>Scream &amp; Shout</h1> - artist: will.i.am & Britney Spears
```

Any idea on how to clear up the  %amp; and add numbering?

Comment: OMG, adding a larger categorie seems to solve the missing artists problem. Now just the numbering remains, and possibly removing the <h1> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
    Elements parents = doc.select("article.song_review");
    for (Element parent : parents)
    {
        Elements position = parent.select("span.chart_position");
        Elements titles = parent.select("h1");
        Elements categories = parent.select("p.chart_info a");
        System.out.print("position: " + position.text() + " - song: " + titles.text() + " - ");
        System.out.print("artist: " + categories.text() + "\n");
    }
```